# What is the 216 digit number in Pi?

Tags: pi

In the movie `Pi`, there is a 216-digit number that the protagonist, Max Cohen, is searching for, which in Kabbalah numerology corresponds to the name of God. What is the actual number used in the film shown on the computer display (Euclid)? (This, of course assumes it is constant every time it appears)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138704/trivia), the number displayed by Euclid actually contains 218 digits:

> 941432434315126593210548723904868285129134748760 2767195923460**23**858295830472501652325259296925727655364363462727 184012012643147546329450127847264841075622347896267285928582953 47502772262646456217613984829519475412398501

The number that Max Cohen writes on paper does have 216 digits (and is completely different); see the link for the digits.

A careful analysis on [another site](http://mike.passwall.com/uselesstrivia/pi.html) says that one of the 216 digits is illegible, but is given as a '9' by IMDb.  It also points out that two digits of the 218-digit number (in bold above) are reversed when they appear on the paper found with Sol Robeson.

Answer (score 6):

> The number 216 is very significant when one multiplies 6x6x6 and
>   receives the result of 216.
>
> The connection to 666 is amplified by its presence in the Darren
>   Aronofsky's film *Pi* where the protagonist stumbles upon a hidden code
>   in the universe, a 216 digit number, which a group of zealous Jews
>   believe to be the true name of god.
>
> In the printout of the 216 digit number, the number 6 can be seen in
>   the beginning of the second, third and fourth rows, forming a vertical
>   666.
>
> The idea of a 216-letter name of god is actually taken from real
>   Jewish history and belief. The 216-letter name of god (the
>   Schemhamphoras) is derived from three verses in Exodus
>   (verses 19, 20, & 21), each being 72 letters long (72x3=216).  Each was
>   written out as a string of letters: verse 19 on top, then 20
>   underneath and in reverse order, and then 21 under that. Reading top to
>   bottom and right to left, the 3 lines of 72 letters yielded 72
>   individual 3 letter names.[1](http://synchromystic.wikia.com/wiki/216)
>
> The number 72 connects to 216 again in the time frames involved with
>   the precession for the equinox. Each of the 12 Ages lasts for 2,160
>   years, and the earth takes 72 years to move one degree in the Great
>   Year. The connection to 12 continues beyond there being 12 Ages, in
>   that the entire cycle lasts about 25,920 years which is 216x120.
>   (Source:[synchromystic.wikia.com](http://synchromystic.wikia.com/wiki/216))

Comment: The coincidence of approximate 26,000 cycle to Mayan...Indian...Egyptian and Assyrian and the more precise Hebrew calculation is not only a time of precession but a unified universal of earth. It would be interesting to examine the precession of other cosmic bodies and more importantly to determine the rate of digression and whether that number is symptomatic of an inevitable end. Is it possible that each division (solar system, galaxy, and even universe) follows the same...in as much as nature is universal also?